# Responsive horizontal scrolling div in indexhibit has too great a width

Tags: css, responsive-design, horizontal-scrolling, indexhibit

I'm building a portfolio in indexhibit where all pages of images use a a horizontal div to scroll through the images.

I didn't like the way the images were reduced in quality and wanted them to appear as large as the visitors screen would allow (without it going over), so I made them responsive (height: 90%; width: auto;).

The trouble is: the horizontal container div has a width that is the size of all of the original images (as per the indexhibit formatting is built to) - leaving a large white space to the right of all the images. This is because the images are downsized to fit the screen responsively - so I guess if you had a big enough screen size these images would actually

If I make the container div width: auto, it obviously splits the images onto the next line.

Is there something I can do with CSS to solve this issue - I'm not confident going in and modifying core files with this cms.

Thanks

Mike Chalmers

Answer (score 0):

I played around with the way the images were displaying and inline-block solved it. The container needs some changes to get it to display horizontally. Here's the basic code:

```
#img-container {
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
}
.img-div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```